# add hours to timestamp / sql activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql, query, sql

I want to add 7 hours to a timestamp value and write the value into another data extension. How can I add these hours?

My poor first try:

```
SELECT
DATEADD(HOUR,+7,dateregister) AS dateregister_new_time 
FROM
customer
```

Comment: what about a formula field with the calculation and query the formula field instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in right direction. Please use the below SQL query.

```
SELECT
DATEADD(hh, 7, dateregister) as dateregister_new_time 
FROM
customer
```

Let me know if this helps